# Mapping Algebraic Normal Form of Exclusive Sum of Products to Toffoli Network

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

How does one map an ANF to a toffoli network? Is there a straight-forward procedure for doing this?

For example, given the ANF for the Sum function of an adder:
$$S = A \oplus B \oplus C \oplus ABC$$

I thought that mapping would be trivial following the process of

1) Perform $A \oplus B$ with two CNOT gates, storing the result in ancilla bit, call it $Anc_1$

2) Perform $Anc_1 \oplus C$ with two CNOT gates, storing the result in $Anc_2$

3) Perform $Anc_2 \oplus ABC$ using a CNOT and a 3-control bit toffoli, storing the result in the output, $S$

This process results in this circuit

[image]

Why does this not work? What is the process to map an ANF to a toffoli network?

Thank you

PS I apologize for not being able to find an appropriate tag.

Comment: Great question! Also, added a few tags (:

Comment: *"Why does this not work?"* is hard to answer when you don't say why you think it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake.
The ANF for the sum function of an adder is 
$$S = A \oplus B \oplus C$$

The process for mapping ANF to toffoli network works, but only if the ANF is correct.

Comment: For completeness of the answer for a later reader, remove step 3 of the circuit construction above.

Comment: Don’t forget to ‘uncompute’ the ancilla s afterwards.